# Server.MapPath throws error 'The Path parameter excedes the maximum length allowed'

Tags: asp-classic

I am using Classic ASP to copy file from a server shared path to root folder of my application. When I use `Server.MapPath()` to get the physical path it is showing the below error

> •Error Type:  Server.MapPath(), ASP 0214 (0x80004005) The Path
>   parameter excedes the maximum length allowed.

The code I use is as below

```
Dim fs, f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CopyFile Server.MapPath(dirdefault + rs1("location")), Server.MapPath(location1)
```

Here `dirdefault+rs1("location")` gives the shared path with filename. The number of characters coming for any 1 shared path is a maximum of 70 characters including spaces.

Kindly suggest an alternate way to copy files to my destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dirdefault+rs1("location") should be dirdefault & rs1("location") instead…?